# Capitalization of Phrases: One-on-one assistance

Tags: editing

What is the correct capitalization of the phrase "One-on-one assistance"?

- One-on-one assistance
- One-on-One assistance
- One-on-One Assistance

I am using it in a lower third title in a video.

Comment: John, your question already has an answer [in this question](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/which-words-should-not-be-capitalized-in-title-case). Welcome to the site, and please continue to ask questions here. (You might also find out sister site [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) to be helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

Used as a title: "One-on-One Assistance".